# Incorrect time in accepted answer tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

In some questions that have an accepted answer, the tooltip in the green tick has the wrong timestamp.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623062/why-was-googles-chrome-browser-written-almost-entirely-in-c-and-not-c-or-java) for an example. The tooltip says

> The question owner accepted this as the best answer 0 secs ago

It says this no matter when you go to the question.

It doesn't happen on all questions. Perhaps it is something to do with the question being a wiki or having had a bounty?

Answer (score 3):

> **Edit 2:**
>   In [a tangentially related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26038/bug-in-mouseover-of-the-green-checkmark-for-answers-winning-a-bounty), Jeff confirmed that this odd date situation is related to deleted users and marked the bug [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). This seems to confirm what Tim Stone found (see edit 1, below this).

---

> **Edit:**
>   As pointed out by Tim Stone [in the chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/257728#257728), this is likely because the user who asked the question has been deleted (or for some other reason no longer exists).

I'm now seeing this on mouseover:

> The question owner accepted this as the best answer Jan 1 '01 at 0:00

The completely expanded [timeline view](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/623062/timeline) — perhaps unsurprisingly — don't show any indication of when the actual acceptance took place.

I don't see any indication of a bounty, including inside [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/623062/revisions), though it's possible that it's being hidden by the same bug. Do you know for sure that there was one, or were you making an educated guess?

The [very oldest CW question on SO with an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time) doesn't show this bug, so it's not an age thing.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when sock puppets [get merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71501/possible-cheating-via-sock-puppet-account). In that case, maybe the timestamp could be preserved? Like [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351581/array-with-hello-world/4351587#4351587):

[image: Odd timestamp]