# When the last editor is deleted, the gravatar of the post owner is shown instead

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, user-interface, deleted-accounts

I ran into [an old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql/723209#723209) and saw my gravatar twice on a single answer.  Apparently, the guy who edited the post had his account deleted, and the site engine is failing to display something acceptable.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8621/incorrect-time-in-accepted-answer-tooltip

Comment: @Jeff Is the [status-completed] addressing the behavior documented in Gnome's answer to this question? Because if so, I'm not sure it's working (see [the latest duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115801/why-does-asked-and-edited-shows-the-same-person)). Could you explain what was changed?

Comment: Well, this is obviously not status-completed, since I just reproduced it on this very post...

Comment: @NineShogsShogging: LOL!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed in the next build; after that, the editor will be the standard anonymous avatar just like for posts *created* by deleted users.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another example of, seemingly, the same bug.

The previous editor is listed incorrectly:

[image: screenshot]

If that account has been deleted:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How ironic that Gnome is now deleted.

Comment: @Popular and now the question itself (as long as no one edits it now) serves as reproduction itself!