# Community-created revisions attributed to owner

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, community-user

Sometime in the last day or so, the [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)-created revisions that add the "Possible Duplicate" box to posts closed as duplicates started showing up on the post itself as edits by the owner. For example, on the post [Sign on separate line in vote count for low-score mod nominations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76739/sign-on-separate-line-in-vote-count-for-low-score-mod-)

[image: Screenshot of the post]

The edit by Simon Brown was actually by Community, and shows up correctly in the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/76739/revisions). The same thing happened on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76684/allow-users-with-edit-privileges-to-approve-peer-edits-with-one-click) 5 hours ago, and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818001/do-any-one-have-gdb-py-file-or-its-link) 2 hours ago. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805336/how-to-assign-an-icon-to-a-language) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803602/lambda-expressions-why-no-argument-type-inference) SO posts that both closed yesterday are correct (they show no revision on the main page, and Community in the history)

Comment: Nice catch. I've seen [similar to this before when the latest editor of a post was deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18754/edit-timestamp-screws-up-when-the-last-editor-is-deleted), but this is clearly not the case in this scenario.

Comment: What? But Community can't be Simon Brown's sockpuppet; [it's Jon B's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62557/why-is-the-community-user-accepting-answers)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this was fixed long ago (to be precise: on the same day you reported this). It was a side effect of a change that had the purpose to support the (then-new) suggested edits, but which had several undesired effects (also including the closing of a question to bump a post).

So this issue is (at most) only visible on questions that were closed as dupes *on that day*. In addition, the fix for [When the last editor is deleted, the gravatar of the post owner is shown instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18754/when-the-last-editor-is-deleted-the-gravatar-of-a-previous-editor-is-shown-inst) also affects this very case; after that's deployed, there won't be a double-signature anymore on those post; instead, the "anonymous avatar" will be shown as the editor, without a display name.

Granted, that's not 100% correct, but since it only affects very few posts (namely those that were closed as dupes on the day this bug was active, *and* have not been edited since) and isn't a real problem, I don't think it's worth doing some historical data fixup for this.