# Last edit shows unlinked deleted user, but revision list shows user still exists

Tags: support, revisions-list, deleted-accounts

If you go to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat), you will see the following:

> [image: last edit made by deleted user]

It appears as if the user has been deleted -- neither their icon appears, nor are you able to click on it.

But this isn't the case. When [looking at the revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3330/revisions) you can clearly see that the user does still exist:

> [image: revisions history showing not deleted user]

Why is that the case?

Comment: The question was asked and edited in 2009, so I would assume that there was a change to how questions are displayed that wasn't backwards compatible, but I'll leave it to the older users and devs who might actually know why.

Comment: That user hasn't always been never not deleted

Comment: @zzzzBov I was thinking the same thing.. but look at [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3163/how-can-we-be-more-tolerant-of-humor). It was edited 8 days prior to the one that doesn't display the name, yet it doesn't seem affected by the (bug?)

Comment: @random I will be up all night parsing that comment. Maybe I can use Regular Expressions to help...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A long time ago that user made an edit to the post.

Then their account was deleted.

Then their account was undeleted.

You are now seeing remnants of [their ghost trail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18754/when-the-last-editor-is-deleted-the-gravatar-of-the-post-owner-is-shown-instead) between when they were deleted and resurrected.

When [a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115656/when-an-account-is-deleted-how-much-of-personal-data-is-retained-about-the-accou), their name on the edit is denormalised and leaves that blank profile image and de-linked name.

When the account was undeadified most things got put back. But like Frankenstein's Eckhart, not all pieces came back.

Comment: So.. this isn't a bug then?

Comment: Don't think it's a bug. And you would have to have some history of various users, especially Diago's case here, to recognise why this name in particular would appear like this. Also, it's rare now that a deleted account would be undeleted. It's way too much hassle