# Mouseover of the green checkmark for answers winning a bounty shows wrong time

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, bounties

If you hover over the green checkmark on an answer that has won a bounty (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623062/why-was-googles-chrome-browser-written-almost-entirely-in-c-and-not-c-or-java/644292#644292)), you will see that the time it was selected is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Due to deleted users. Note that user "polk" who was the original author no longer exists.

We now don't show the date of accept at all in these cases.