# Why did I not receive +15 rep for an accepted answer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, accepted-answer

The question I refer to is: [C++ arrays and size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781208/c-arrays-and-size)

Mine is the accepted answer, but I have received no rep for it (checked using stackoverflow.com/reputation)

Although I hit my rep cap on the day in question (yesterday) I understand that the accept bonus is still meant to be awarded. I can see on other days where I hit my cap that accept bonuses were awarded.

I'm not going to cry about this but I felt it my duty to report what appears to be a bug.  If it's not a bug and is by design then I apologise for time wasting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The user account of the question asker was deleted. As [deleted users do not provide reputation for acceptance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73886/do-we-lose-rep-for-an-accepted-answer-if-the-op-account-is-deleted/73887#73887), you won't earn 15 reputation from it. Not a particularly common occurrence, but it does strike the best of us sometimes.

Comment: What would have caused that user to have been deleted so quickly?

Comment: @Kev Deletions are normally by request.

Comment: How odd that you'd ask a question, then within 24hrs request that your account to be deleted - are people really that strange?

Comment: @Kev I can't explain it any better than that. The other primary source of deletion would be lack of any sort of activity, and even posting one question is enough to stymy that, nevermind the base +2 for accepting an answer that'd keep you above 1 rep.

Answer (score 14):

When a user is deleted the acceptance votes will now be moved to community, so that 15 rep will not disappear.  This change has been active for a little while now, just unannounced (it fixed a bug on the back-end).

Comment: Thanks for this, although it seems like a comment to the question rather than an answer....   ;-)

Comment: @Nick - this change isn't retrospective is it?  See for example SO post  2061243 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73886/do-we-lose-rep-for-an-accepted-answer-if-the-op-account-is-deleted

Comment: @martin - no, it is not, though we need to do *some* fixup of old accept votes in a few cases.