# Wiping votes on deletion of highly active accounts (-865 points on "User was removed")

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, deleted-accounts

**Update:** As MadScientist quite aptly [pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173045/wiping-votes-on-deletion-of-high-rep-accounts-865-points-on-user-was-removed#comment514105_173045) this is also highly relevant:

- [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) at **+523** votes, [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I was greeted by this screen just an hour ago:

[image: Screenshot of reputation tab showing the entry “-865: User was removed”.]

After a little bit of digging and conjecturing, I worked out that the user removed was user llonesmiz.

I dearly bemoan the loss of a great SO contributor, and my (near) lone companion in [[boost-spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-spirit)]. I know they had personal reasons for deleting their account, as I have tried to help/talk to them in comments over the last few months.

---

Now, I'll be honest. I don't like losing the reputation.

On a more principled level I'm trying to work out the following questions:

- Is it fair/desirable that a user takes with them all the votes they had cast on account deletion?

  In my view, this was a highly respected power user with a lot of reputation in the [[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++)] domain. Their votes *matter to me*. Frequently, they taught me much better ways to do stuff, so I think it is a **distinct disservice to the community** to wipe their votes.
- Should high reputation accounts be deleted instead of being destroyed?

  - see also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131666/159703) for “delete” vs. “destroy”

  I'm not sure if according to ^that^ explanation the account should have been destroyed. If it was, maybe the criterion should be tuned a bit more.

---

**P.S.** On my search across meta before posting this question I found the following things to be relevant:

- the above linked-to answer: [What EXACTLY happens when I ask to delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131665/what-exactly-happens-when-i-ask-to-delete-my-account/131666#131666)
- [Do we lose rep for an accepted answer if the OP account is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73886/do-we-lose-rep-for-an-accepted-answer-if-the-op-account-is-deleted)
- [What EXACTLY happens when I ask to delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131665/what-exactly-happens-when-i-ask-to-delete-my-account)

Comment: This got me today, too.

Comment: **-865**.  Holy crap.

Comment: I was going to ask you to provide link to the user's profile `:|`.

Comment: You're misunderstanding `delete` vs. `destroy`, both remove all the votes but `destroy` also removes all the posts. And my feature request to stop deleting all votes for deleted users (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) might also be of interest to you.

Comment: `-36` for me. Literally hundreds of people could lose rep.

Comment: How often will a single user's votes make a meaningful difference in the ranking of the answers of any single question? It could happen, but I imagine not very often.

Comment: [User in question](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Y7Wr4hFGAOsJ:stackoverflow.com/users/1252091/llonesmiz+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) had "only" 1710 rep which I don't consider high (easily achieved in 1 month). He just casts relatively a lot of votes: at least 2362 upvotes of which 1716 on answers (and thus generating 17K rep). You might want to reframe the question accordingly.

Comment: @Chichiray bear in mind that's a month-old cache so numbers could be off a bit

Comment: Because sockpuppets.  How do you distinguish a genuine account from a sock?

Comment: @Chichiray I don't feel the question needs reframing. The linked source clearly says "This can only be done to users with ***a very low reputation***, unless you are a StackExchange employee". 1.7k is very clearly ***not*** very low reputation. If you think otherwise you might want to check the rep distribution statistics of SO users.

Comment: @joran It's not about losing rep, it's about ***losing expert opinions***. You might have missed the fact that I'm asking about "in principle". I'm far from alone in thinking [that legitimate votes cast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) should not be deleted. I don't care too much about the rep. I care about destruction of knowledge (or at least the quantitative endorsements of it)

Comment: I understood you just fine I think, but I think you didn't understand me at all. My point is that the one vote that a single user contributes to a set of answers usually won't change the impression of which answer was best. (Accepts are a different story though.) My comment had absolutely nothing to do with lost rep. At all. Read it again.

Comment: `-80` rep for me today

Comment: The case of a long-standing highly respected user requesting self-deletion of their account should be handled differently from a sock puppet being destroyed. (Edit: ah. According to gnat, that was supposed to happen.)

Comment: Not on topic but I am really, really curious if you don't mind sharing, why did the user delete his account? Lately, SO has been turning into a different place than it used to be and all these long time users suddenly leaving is starting to worry me, because it may indicate that we have a bigger problem at hand.

Comment: @l46kok: All what long time users? One mid-rep guy leaves, and suddenly there's a flood of users leaving?

Comment: @l46kok Nah. I don't think it's relevant. Also, I'd really be guessing. The ***point*** is, that it's not relevant. Some users _should_ be deleted, but some just "want" to be gone, and this is the case here.

Comment: @sehe: If he just wanted to be gone, why did he ask to be deleted? Personally, asking to be deleted sounds more like rage-quitting to me than merely leaving. If he wanted to leave, just don't come back.

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz: Let's hope we don't receive hundreds of comments from them stating exactly how much rep they've lost.

Comment: @NicolBolas I hear you. That's worth my +1. However, like I said he might have had personal reasons to actual want deletion, or "dissociation".. I can only point to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233565/cannot-phoenixbind-qi-val-with-boost-1-53-regression#comment21496386_15233565 ([backup in lounge<c++>](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8308781#8308781)). I might not understand it, but I do respect his request to be, effectively, disowned from his account.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This was our screw-up, and preventing large impact deletes like this will be an addition to the code on our side sometime this week.

For now I've gone through the database and manually undone the delete action on this user's votes, which is the net impact that *should* have happened if they were moved to the community user...our normal process.

Your rep history (and about 1,300 other users) will no longer reflect this user's deletion.

Comment: This is a great reponse. Thanks for the pleasant surprise. Also, the fact that it is now on the radar for future cases is the take-away for SO.

Comment: You might want to tag this [tag:status-complete]..

Comment: @Seth I will. (Why the hurry?) Note that this question was a [meta-tag:discussion]. I agree that consensus has emerged. However, also note that the implementation isn't complete ("preventing...will be...sometime this week"). \@Nick if you prefer to track the status of that [over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740/159703) instead, feel free to mark this as [meta-tag:status-complete]. I'm happy as long as it receives the attention :)

Comment: Was the feature actually implemented? I lost a few points with reason "user was removed", so I'd like some feedback here.

Comment: It is not clear how "large impact" is defined and when this should and shouldn't happen.  I lost 80 rep today (not a lot, I know) because [user 2875617](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2875617/francesco) was removed. He probably only had a couple hundred rep and 50 or so votes, so I understand this didn't get special treatment, but I am curious as to when such vote-preserving deletion is used. Just browsing through other [matlab] users, I see many people have lost rep, so it does not seem to be a cross-voting user or anything shady like that.

Comment: Just this user? Why not other users as well?

Comment: @Blaisorblade nope, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245995/which-users-getting-removed-dont-cause-rep-changes-lost-1600-rep) pretty much proves the code does not prevent deleting users with thousands of votes.

Comment: Nick Is there an answer to this question: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5663/99274?

Comment: "You might want to tag this status-complete" "I will" (6 years pass)

Comment: @DewiMorgan To be fair, only employees can do that.

Answer (score 57):

As far as I can tell, this is **not** how deletion of such user accounts is supposed to happen.

The procedure has been outlined by SE developer in an [answer to similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156520/165773) as follows:

> When we delete **highly active users upon their request** (i.e. they no longer wish to participate in Stack Exchange), **we preserve their up/down/accepted votes** by moving them to our Community User.

Unless I miss something, loss of 865 points and [2000+ votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173045/wiping-votes-on-deletion-of-high-rep-accounts-865-points-on-user-was-removed/173071?noredirect=1#comment514129_173045) suggest that user qualifies as "highly active".

The fact that votes weren't preserved indicates either a bug like one that has been confirmed at above post ("bug in our vote auto-invalidation task"), or, maybe, that removal somehow (how?) did not happen "upon their request".

Comment: It depends on how you define "highly active". His rep probably didn't qualify him as such.

Comment: @NicolBolas if they qualify "highly active" solely by rep, they're on a road to trouble. I for one had thousands votes on Programmers and SO (and MSO, and Workplace) even before I got 2-3K. Dropping stuff I cast if I decide to leave would most certainly muddy some waters (not that it will be my headache though:)

Comment: "highly active" is subjective/relative. In the [tag:boost-spirit] tag he was _clearly_ active. He specialized in template metaprogramming and [tag:boost-library] internals. Those are highly specialized tag and few SO users take the :effort: to answer/read/vote these questions. (In this respect, his votes constitute probably a significant 'weight' in the total vote volumes there)

Comment: @sehe Thank you for finally responding to what I actually wrote in my comment. If the user is active in a more marginal tag, this will dramatically increase the likelihood that their votes on any particular question will effect the ordering/perceived usefulness of specific answers. _That_ was what I was trying to get you to expand upon, not rep loss.

Comment: @joran Ok. I can see it now :) I think your point might be so essential to the discussion, it might be worth posting as an answer

Comment: It's a manual process - and one which was overlooked in this case. Not to go into detail, but it's probably not robust enough to make this automatic - so we can't ever promise that it will or won't happen, but in cases where the disruption will likely be high we do try to minimize it.

Comment: @Shog9 interesting. Now that you mention that, I feel like _moving votes to Community User_ is sort of a user merge process, the one that goes through Community Team (as explained in [February 2013 Moderator Newsletter](http://moderator.stackexchange.com/2013/03/february-2013-newsletter/))... Delicate and complicated stuff, right?

Comment: It's a little bit different (we've fixed the most obvious/unfortunate side-effect of suddenly giving Community a crapload of votes, but there are almost certainly more subtle ones). At best, it's a hack to work around the fact that we actually do *hard delete* user accounts - I'm fairly sure it's not something we could do routinely without causing... Interesting problems. The primary concern when merging *users* is just not inadvertently exposing credentials.

Comment: @Shog9 REALLY? Now that takes me by surprise. If there's no way to fix it, then I suggest a safety measure (an alert message) of some kind is order. This is _certainly_ not the first time it happened this way: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5540467#5540467 just one very well recorded incident

Comment: @sehe: this case is... exceptional though, both because of the amount of votes involved, and the number of people affected. Deleting users with this much voting activity is very, very rare; as I said before, I don't think it's something we can automate at this point, but... A warning or sanity check of some sort is probably a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

> In my view, this was a highly respected power user with a lot of reputation in the c++ domain. His votes matter to me. Frequently, he taught me much better ways to do stuff, so, if this user cast a vote, I think it is a distinct disservice to the community to wipe his votes.

Voting is, more or less, anonymous. Yes, you can kinda figure out who voted on what, if you really investigate or poll the database directly. But you can't tell just from looking at a question or answer who voted for it. So I don't see how wiping his votes impacts how someone looks at a question/answer he voted on.

Furthermore, the account is deleted. "The community" no longer knows he existed. He has been *unpersoned*. Nobody in the community can find him or his contributions, let alone his *votes*.

So I don't see how the community is dis-served here.

> Is it fair/desirable that a user takes with him all the votes he had cast on account deletion?

Personally, I don't think that account deletion should be allowed, period. However, if they're going to allow it then yes, they should be completely unpersoned. With the exception of the text they wrote (the primary contribution of a user), the site should be as though they never were here.

And they shouldn't be allowed to have their old accounts, no matter how much they beg.

The reason for this is simple: to *discourage* people from deleting their accounts. If deletion were painless and/or easily reversible, then people would be doing it more often. Deletion has negative effects. You can't easily find other questions/answers from a user who posted a good question/answer you liked. You can't track a deleted account. And so forth. Even if votes aren't removed, deletion damages Stack Overflow.

So we make deletion *hurt*. That way, it only gets used in the most critical of circumstances.

Comment: Just because the user no longer has an account here does not mean the posts he/she voted on were any less helpful. I believe it is wrong to remove those votes, as the posts they voted on were helpful in the past and the deletion of the user's account does not change that.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I'm 100% sure this was the user. I have [simply checked](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=8426245#8426245) by revisiting his comments/contributions. Also, it explains perfectly how I was the most impacted, as we shared a common "niche" interest: [tag:boost-spirit]

Comment: @sehe: I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm saying that this information is *not available*. You only found out because you know him well and you know his wandering habits. For "the community", he was a guy who voted a lot; nothing more.

Comment: I don't care about what ***[Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)*** thinks :) I care about what SO thinks. The _real_ community, that is

Comment: @sehe: Then why do you care if it's a "distinct disservice to the community" or not?

Comment: "So I don't see how the community is dis-served here" - he was one of the few contributors both qualified and interested in scrutinizing a niche of questions, the type that take more effort on average. Removing his votes makes it hard for community members to judge whether existing content is worth it's salt, because there is literally too little interest for any significant voting (beyond the 'thank you' votes from the OP)

Comment: @sehe: The C++ tag is the seventh-most-popular tag on SO. And virtually every Boost-Spirit question is tagged with it, for obvious reasons. I see no reason why his vote was somehow keeping stuff on that tag from becoming a bunch of zero vote questions and answers. Indeed, skimming through the first page of questions on that tag, I don't see any evidence of the problem you suggest at all.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm +1 this answer because I do agree that deleting accounts should not really be an option (exceptional "moderational" reasons aside). However, you answer seemed to me to state "I don't think it's relevant". I did disagree there. Which of those two was the strongest message you intended to send?

Comment: @NicolBolas also, (OT) let me take the opportunity to thank you for [occasionally contributing](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a734069%20%5bboost-spirit%5d) to [tag:boost-spirit] :)

Comment: `So we make deletion hurt.` For everyone other than the person being deleted? If someone wants their account deleted badly enough, I don't see why they would care about the impact of their deletion on others.

Comment: @NicolBolas "I don't see any evidence of the problem you suggest at all." - try actively monitoring [the feed](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/boost-spirit) for a year or two. Then we'll talk again. Seriously, this tag has too few contributors, and frequently I post an answer that goes without a single response for days. I can only conclude that all the c++ regulars just skip on it as "too much effort"/"too specific". This is certainly true of the people I know (they actively refer those questions to me, nevermind I'm subscribed :))

Comment: @NicolBolas Would you mind repeating your claim ("I don't see any evidence of the problem you suggest at all.") now? I mean, just an example: [obvious NARQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209507) sits for 15+hours with ~15 views. I cast the first close vote/comment (and linked it in the lounge to get some traction). I can really conclude none other than you are clearly underestimating the niche effect. (Possibly by over-estimating your own involvement, and that of other [tag:c++] frequenters by proxy). And this is only scratching the surface, really. <rant/>

Comment: @sehe: The "problem you suggest" was specifically that "*Removing his votes makes it hard for community members to judge whether existing content is worth it's salt, because there is literally too little interest for any significant voting (beyond the 'thank you' votes from the OP)*" A *new* question remaining unopened for 15+ hours has *nothing to do with that problem*. Furthermore, don't complain to me about crap questions that say open for 15 hours until you've spent time in the OpenGL tag where many crap questions *do not get closed* ever. Not unless they have `C++` or a popular tag on it.

Comment: Ah, so you _do_ recognize the issues. Well, then. The (what I believed to be obvious) corollary to this phenomenon of very low traffic, is that almost no-one will upvote answers except for the OP. This implies that removing _all votes_ by one of ~2 active users in a tag for some months is indeed reducing all answers to identical scores of ~1 ("thank you") and perhaps ~2-3 ("seen it, looks ok"; mostly happens when I announce my answer in the chat only). This effectively removes the community confirmation value of votes.

Comment: @sehe: Then the community member who decided to forcibly disassociate himself from the community should have considered that before forcibly disassociating himself from it. He didn't *have* to delete his account, you know. He could have just left it there. If someone wants to be a jerk to the community by taking their ball and going home, I'm fine with unpersoning them and all of their non-textual contributions, no matter the consequences. Let that be a lesson to anyone else who might want to delete their account because they're angry over some pointless slight.

Comment: @NicolBolas I get the impression you don't want to discuss it. First you say it's not an issue, then you have me explain how I removing votes by high-rep users in low-traffic tags harms the tag community; Now you say "well, it's just that way"? That lacks logic, since **(a)** the user did likely _not know_ about said consequences **(b)** this is [not supposed to happen, even at account deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173071/159703) in the first place **(c)** the leaving user might not have the community interest in mind at that time (_in extremo_ this is like a DoS vulnerability)

Comment: What's the lesson? "You can delete your account and not only you'll achieve your goal, you'll also take away potentially thousands of reputation points from others!"? Yeah that's seems like a grave consequence for someone who wants to remove their account

Comment: @CatPlusPlus More specificly here, I was noting the harm done by removing upvotes from posts, aside from the rep potentially lost. Note how the wrong [was righted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173699/159703) already - so both points have been fixed _for this particular incident_. I'm just discussing with Nicol why the votes matter, specificy in [tag:boost-spirit]

Comment: @sehe You can substitute rep for votes and it still makes the same amount of sense i.e. none.

Comment: @sehe: "*I was noting the harm done by removing upvotes from posts, aside from the rep potentially lost.*" You *still* haven't shown any harm. Where is your *actual data* from the database that says that a significant percentage of questions have become "unanswered"? Granted, it's hard to say what the "damage" would have been since it's been undone. But my point is that, besides some people losing rep, there has been no evidence showing any actual *harm* to the site or to the Boost.Spirit tag. And your pointing to a new question the person couldn't have voted on is a non-sequitur.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: "*Yeah that's seems like a grave consequence for someone who wants to remove their account*" It keeps people from removing their accounts for silly, petty reasons. They have to actually be spiteful to do it now. And quite frankly, if you're that kind of person, we didn't need your contributions anyway.

Comment: "And quite frankly, if you're that kind of person, we didn't need your contributions anyway" - how's that for non-sequitur? (For the record: "And your pointing to a new question the person couldn't have voted on is a non-sequitur" is a straw man. I haven't said that. I have explained what I meant. Feel free to ignore. Good day.)

Comment: "It keeps people from removing their accounts for silly, petty reasons." Why would it? They're not affected by any of this in the slightest, they just want their account removed. The reason is not really important here (SO should have a self-service "remove account" button anyway).

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Why should we make it easy for people to remove their account? Account removal is something that should *only* happen if it is something that a person *needs* to do for professional reasons, like if they can't have their name associated with some posting of theirs. I don't know of any web-forum that allows people to "remove" their accounts at all, not without directly contacting the webmaster.

Comment: Because they might not want to have an account here. Why should we make it *hard*? Any decent site *will* have self-service account removal functionality. I don't know what crappy Internet forums have to do with this. I thought SO was supposed to be better than those? Account removal is something that should happen when person doesn't want to have an account here any more, and it's nobody business why (there are even laws for this sort of thing I wonder why).

Comment: European countries have data privacy laws regarding that matter. I'm a bit fuzzy on how it works for a company outside of Europe, but nonetheless I've come to the expectation that websites provide the functionality to remove a user from their files, out of courtesy if not obligation.