# Rep -100 due to user deletion (shouldn't this be -10?)

Tags: discussion, reputation

Today I noticed in my rep calculation a *"-100 user was removed"*. I'm aware of the reason that votes on answers are rolled back if users who did the vote got removed. But that would account to only -10.

Now I have a single -100 line, which would either mean, that either

**1.** 10 users who all did vote on one of my answer got removed at the same time (very unlikely)

**2.** I guess it could be that the votes were on a anwer to a *question* of a particular user and got rolled back because the answer got rolled back

or

**3.** There's a bug somewhere the StackExchange

The case (2) is somewhat counterintuitive. It would mean that questions and their answers got removed, (just) because a user got removed. Even if the user did violate the StackExchange rules at some point, this would be yet no reason to legitimate the loss of knowledge.

Comment: or because the user upvoted 10 of your answers...

Comment: A user upvoted 10 different answers of yours, or 20 questions, or some combination of those.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173045/wiping-votes-on-deletion-of-highly-active-accounts-865-points-on-user-was-rem - possibly related, given that you're active in C++

Comment: @Mat: Oh, yeah, didn't thin of that. If you make this an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: (1) is very unlikely, and not at all what would have happened. If 10 different users had been removed, you would have 10 different "User was removed" entries in your reputation history. This event simply means that a user was removed that had gained you a total of +100 reputation, which has now been reversed.

Comment: @animuson: Mat did already state the likely reason.

Answer (score 0):

The system behind reputation calculation is a simple sum over all the upvotes you have.

When a user removed the account all of their votes were removed too, and the rep you gained from them (and now lost) was revoked. Thus, the sum changes.

---

The question already exists with a different title here [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/212576)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this, but I was puzzled by the -100; of course at Mat already pointed out, the user could have cast votes on 10 of my answers. Silly me.