# Getting Reputation for a deleted user?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Recently I noticed a drop of my reputation, when a user was removed. IIRC it was like:

```
-2 User was removed
-15 User was removed
```

When I logged in today I noticed, that my reputation was back up again.
When looking into my profile I noticed, that the negative reputation changes related to the removal of the user have gone and instead I now see:

[image: Getting +2 reputation for a removed user]

Because of this I have two questions:

1. Is this correct behaviour or a bug?
2. How about getting +2 rep for removed users whom I did not reply to? ;)

Comment: That user probably downvoted one of your posts.

Comment: The user had downvoted one of your answers. When a user is removed, so are their votes.

Comment: I have no image of the previous state but IIRC there were two entries related to this which did -2 and -15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A user who downvoted you was later removed, this is what should have happened.

Comment: If it is so, then why did I get a -2 and -15 for this removal the last time I checked?

Comment: @Nobody - Because the -15 was deleted as part of a correction here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173045/wiping-votes-on-deletion-of-highly-active-accounts-865-points-on-user-was-rem/173699#173699  Only the positive votes for that user were restored, since the fault was ours.

Comment: But this still does not explain why the -2 became a +2 or did I miss something there?

Comment: @Nobody - Because the -15 was from an unaccept, which can not be restored as it would not have an accept to tie to, so you got the downvote reversed only.

Comment: I think you misundestood: When the user was deleted I got two entries in the rep log: `-2 user was deleted` and `-15 user was deleted`. Why would I get another -2 for a deleted user who downvoted me when he is deleted?

Comment: @Nobody Are you sure the `+2` wasn't already there yesterday (and not a -2)? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: @Nobody - you never had a -2 in the log, you had a +2 and a -15 (one vote on an answer, one on a question), I've verified this data 3 different ways and each of the records agree.

Comment: @NickCraver: Then I probably remembered wrongly. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Nobody - it's not an inconvenience at all, we want to make sure there are no bugs and rep is correct, same as you :)