# Does deleting an account uncheck the accepted answers?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, deleted-accounts

In my opinion the accepted answer should permanently stick as only the original question submitter has the ability to accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the answer acceptance stays.  Here's [an example](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/24788/1993) of a question from a deleted user with an accepted answer.

The author of that answer retained the earned reputation.  (As a moderator I can see when the user account was deleted, so I checked reputation events on both that day and the day the answer was accepted.  The deletion didn't affect the answerer's reputation.)  Based on a suggestion from CrazyIvan in a comment, I checked the Community user and [found](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=accepts) the acceptance event there.

One exception: if the deleted account was ever involved in voting fraud, all votes are removed regardless of recipient ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/162102)).

Comment: Technically, acceptance is transferred to Community who ends up with a lot of accept actions in its profile.

Comment: Is this answer outdated? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73887/378231

Comment: @user198350 yes. This is the up to date official answer about how this work these days: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/152859