# Accepted answers are all accepted at Jan 1 '01 at 0:00

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

I've just noticed on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70351/how-many-files-i-can-have-on-a-single-directory/70370#70370) that accepted answers are always being marked as accepted on January 1st, '01 at midnight. This applies to SO as well. Screenshot below for [PDO bindParam Timestamp is not inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908042/pdo-bindparam-timestamp-is-not-inserted/7908087#7908087):

[image: The question owner accepted this as the best answer Jan 1 '01 at 0:00]

It's not limited to new questions or answers, the [first accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/when-setting-a-forms-opacity-should-i-use-a-decimal-or-double/7#7) is affected too.

Comment: It appears to be network wide. Same on Programmers

Comment: Also the case on Meta, which is still on rev 2011.10.26.1 as opposed to 2011.10.26.2.

Comment: This is not the first time IIRC

Comment: The first time was Jan 1 '01 at 0:00.

Comment: @Rosinante - Yep, that bug report is at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8621/incorrect-time-in-accepted-answer-tooltip  It was an issue with deleted accounts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was the result of craziness, it's fixed in the build that just went out across all sites, enjoy!

Comment: A Craviness, that explainz... Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed to work for the three answers in question and this one

Comment: @sehe - It was a missing "?", no...I'm not kidding about that :)