# Bug in time for answer accept tick tooltip is wrong (Jan 1'01 at 0:00)

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer, timestamps, tooltips

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accepted answers are all accepted at Jan 1 '01 at 0:00](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110392/accepted-answers-are-all-accepted-at-jan-1-01-at-000)

It appears that the time in the tooltip for accepted answer tick is (always?) wrong:

[image]

I sampled a fair number of my most recent accepted answers and all of them show **`Jan 1'01 at 0:00`**.

I'm aware of the fact that this resembles this question: [Incorrect time in accepted answer tooltip](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8621/incorrect-time-in-accepted-answer-tooltip). However, that question is old (2009) and apparently was marked as resolved (? confusing tags for me)

Comment: How about [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110392/accepted-answers-are-all-accepted-at-jan-1-01-at-000) from 2 hours ago?

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: hah that was fast. voting as duplicate then (can I vote for my own answer?). (Now let's find whether there was a bug in the search results too, or just in my content scanning ability...?)

Comment: I'm not sure about voting to close, but you can just delete it yourself (no voting required).

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: hey hey; I don't want to delete a post I just spent 15 minutes writing :) Besides, it documents that more people are independently reporting the bug as problematic (means something else than that a bug receives upvotes: upvotes are way more passive could merely be a _reaction_ rather than an initiative). But, that's meta-so-psychology